# MIDI-USB connection not recognized by Ubuntu

Tags: usb, hardware, usb-device, dmesg

I've got a digital piano and an A/B MIDI-USB cable plugged into it, to my PC in order to use it as MIDI controller.

For an inexplicable reason, the connection is not recognized. `lsusb` does not list the device, and `dmesg` outputs the following:

```
usb 2-3: new full-speed USB device number 30 using xhci_hcd
usb 2-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 2-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 2-3: new full-speed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd
usb 2-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 2-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb usb2-port3: attempt power cycle
usb 2-3: new full-speed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
usb 2-3: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 2-3: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 2-3: device not accepting address 32, error -71
usb 2-3: new full-speed USB device number 33 using xhci_hcd
usb 2-3: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 2-3: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 2-3: device not accepting address 33, error -71
usb usb2-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
```

My research on the `read/64, error -71` message online amounts to 'change USB port' or 'reboot', both of which did not help, or to faulty hardware. However (and this is the frustrating part) I know that the piano, cable and all my USB ports work, since when I boot my PC under Windows 10 everything works fine !

I have the `midisport-firmware`, `a2jmidid` packages and whatnot, but they should not be the issue since the OS itself doesn't seem to acknowledge my piano.

I'm running an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

**EDIT :**
After further research, I think it's possible that my cable is too long (it's several meters) and the signal sent by my computer never reaches the other end (which is still weird considering Windows can do it).
I will try to get my hands on a shorter cable to see if that helps.

In the meantime, do any of you know if it's possible for the signal sent by Ubuntu to be weaker than the one with the exact same hardware on Windows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I was right in my edit : the long cable was at fault.

I got a shorter cable and the piano was immediately seen, recognized, and operational.

relevant `dmesg` output :

```
[38669.743154] usb 2-3: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[38669.908423] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0f54, idProduct=0101
[38669.908428] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[38669.908431] usb 2-3: Product: USB-MIDI
[38670.343673] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
```

relevant `lsusb` output :

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0f54:0101 Kawai Musical Instruments Mfg. Co., Ltd MP6 Stage Piano
```

Though, I still do not know *why* Linux could not establish the connection while Windows was fine with the longer cable (please do tell if you have an explanation).